# Consuming the same node twice in Streaming XSLT

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I am trying to convert some XML to the interstitial JSON representation specified in XSLT 3.0 (for later conversion to JSON via `xml-to-json`). My current XSLT works well as a non-streaming stylesheet, but I'm running into issues during the conversion to streaming. Specifically, there are situations where I need to consume the same node twice, especially in the case of repeating tags in XML, which I am converting to arrays in equivalent JSON representation.

```xml
<xsl:if test="boolean(cdf:AdjudicatorName)">
    <array key="AdjudicatorName">
        <xsl:for-each select="cdf:AdjudicatorName">
            <string>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </string>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </array>
</xsl:if>
```

boolean(cdf:AdjudicatorName) tests for the existance of the tag, and creates an array if so.

This code fails in Oxygen (Saxon-EE) with the following message

```
Template rule is declared streamable but it does not satisfy the streamability rules. * There is more than one consuming operand: {fn:exists(...)} on line {X}, and {<string {(attr{key=...}, ...)}/>} on line {Y}
```

I am aware of the `copy-of` workaround, however, many items in the source file can repeat at the highest level, so use of this approach would yield minimal memory savings.

Comment: For some settings, using e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="node-name()">` might allow to identify a group of adjacent element of e.g. `AdjudicatorName` or others, but as far as I remember, to check whether there is more than one item in the group, you then need to materialize `copy-of(current-group())`. If you need to identify any siblings of the same, i.e. not only adjacent, the only `xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()"` helps but requires the use of `xsl:fork` anyway to allow buffering.

Comment: `xsl:iterate` might also help to "collect" children of the same type but requires you to store what you need in parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like the perfect use case for `xsl:where-populated`:

```
<xsl:where-populated>
    <array key="AdjudicatorName">
        <xsl:for-each select="cdf:AdjudicatorName">
            <string>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </string>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </array>
</xsl:where-populated>
```

The `xsl:where-populated` instruction (which was invented for exactly this purpose) logically evaluates its child instructions, and then eliminates any items in the resulting sequence that are "deemed empty", where an element is deemed empty if it has no children. In a streaming implementation the start tag (`<array>`) will be "held back" until its first child is generated, and when the corresponding end tag (`</array>`) is emitted, the pair of tags will be discarded if there were no intervening children emitted.